# How to show skipped suites in output report for webdriverio

Tags: webdriver-io

We have a situation where we need to display any skipped suite in the output report details.

We are using Webdriverio with Jasmine and the pending() feature at the test suite level as a way to dynamically run certain tests.  We need to have the suite details displayed in our output reports, but the information is completely left out.

Is there any way we can get the output report to show "MySuite" as skipped?

```
describe("MySuite", function() {

    if ( true ) {
        pending("Do not run, Suite feature is not enabled");
    }

    it("Block 1", async function() {
        //Block 1 actions
    });

    it("Block 2", async function() {
        //Block 2 actions
    });
});
```